# Django model_formset not able to edit, save or delete information

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to create a simple modelformset to show multiple copies of the same form. My models.py table is called Driver and it has only one field, driver:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
driver = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.driver if self.driver else ''
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('driver/', DriverCreateView.as_view(), name = "driver-create"),
]
```

My forms.py:

```
class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ['driver']
        # exclude = ("id",)

DriverFormSet = modelformset_factory(Driver, form = DriverForm, fields = ['driver'], extra = 1, max_num=20, can_delete=True)
```

I'm fairly sure the issue is in views.py:

```
class DriverCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  model = Driver
  form_class = DriverForm
  template_name = 'trucking/driver_form.html'
  
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DriverCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['formset'] = DriverFormSet()
    return context

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    formset = DriverFormSet(request.POST)
    form= DriverForm(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
      formset.save()
      if self.request.POST.get('Save_Exit'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/database/')
      if self.request.POST.get('Save'):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/driver/')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'formset': formset})
```

Finally my template driver_form.html:

```
    <form method = "POST">
        <fieldset class = "form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
        
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }} {% endfor %}
        <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" border="0">


            <tbody>
        {% for form in formset %}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <tr>    
                <td class="column_name">{{field.label_tag}}{{field.auto_id}}</td>
                <td class="column_data">{{field}}</td>
                <td class="column_errors">{{field.errors|striptags}}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}

            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2" class="column_submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="Save_Exit" value="Save & Exit" class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" class="submit">
                    <a href="{% url 'database'%}"><input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" class="submit"></a>
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
```

The reason I think it's the views.py file is that I cobbled it together from a number of different sources, and not really sure if the lines I have are really necessary or what am I missing to the form to actually update information. When I edited the `post` function inside the class-based view to `form.save()` instead of `formset.save()`, I would be able to add new fields successfully, but not update or delete the existing fields. I have a feeling that the logic is not captured in the if statements somehow, or the formset is being reset to a default value, perhaps in this line:

```
    context['formset'] = DriverFormSet()
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missed adding `formset` hidden inputs. Those inputs provide `Driver.id` for each form, so django will know which instance to update with which `driver`.

Instead of

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }} {% endfor %}
```

use

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`CreateView` (and all class-based views) are not designed to handle formsets. They are supposed to handle 1 form and 1 instance of model. You will have multiple forms (via formset) and multiple instances of model. Your view will work, but it's not making best use of `CreateView`: you are not using several methods which are supposed to be used, you will have `self.object` and `self.form` which you will never use in your view.

There is nothing wrong with function-based views. Refer to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates). For example:

```
@login_required
def create_drivers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = DriverFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            if request.POST.get('Save_Exit'):
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/database/')
            if request.POST.get('Save'):
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/driver/')
    else:
        formset = DriverFormSet()
    return render(request, 'trucking/driver_form.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. One further question if you don't mind: next to each form field I want to write Driver 1:, Driver 2:, etc. I tried to do this using this line of code: `{{field.label_tag}}{{field.auto_id}}`, but it returns `Driver:id_form-2-driver`

If I try `{{field.id}}` instead, it returns nothing. How can I return the id instead? Appreciate it

Comment: Easiest is to use [loop index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for), like this `{{ field.label_tag }} {{ forloop.parentloop.counter }}`.